# how to share apk file safely instead of sharing in mail?

Tags: android, security, apk, share

I would like to share apk file to client. but through mail i don't think it's safe. Is there any other way to share apk file to others?

and what are the steps we have to follow while sharing apk file for safety purpose

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your apk to Google Drive, right click file on Google Drive -> share this file to your client. Then after your client download successfully, you can delete this file from your Google Drive for safe. Hope it help you.

Comment: yes but there is no differents in mail and drive. is there any other options than drive?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with encrypting the file:

1. Zip the file using a [strong password](https://passwordsgenerator.net/) (replace the `{PASSWORD}` argument with it)

`tar cpvf app.tar app.apk`

`7z a -p {PASSWORD} -mx=9 -mhe -t7z app.7z app.tar`

2. Use [ECDH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman) for the key (password) exchange (for example use [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)))
3. Send the file however you want

For decryption use:

`7z x test.7z`